# How can I make my form input not return any results when it is inputted with an empty query?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, html

I want my form input not to act upon an empty search.

I don't want it to even go to the results page and show an error message.

SO

how can I have it so nothing happens when clicking the submit/pressing enter OR pressing space bar then enter?

Can this be done with javascript?

HTML:

```
 <form action="search.php" method="post">
 Search: <input type="text" name="term" /><br />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
 </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$conn = mysql_connect("", "", "")
or die    (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("testable");

if (!$conn) {
echo "Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}

$term = addcslashes($term,'%_');

$term = "%" . $_POST["term"] . "%";



if (!mysql_select_db("weezycouk_641290_db2")) {
echo "Unable to select mydbname: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}

**if (isset($_POST['term']) && ($_POST['term'] !== '')) {
$term = $_POST['term'];
$safe_term = mysql_real_escape_string($term);
$sql = "SELECT FName,LName,Phone
FROM   testable
WHERE  FName LIKE '%". mysql_real_escape_string($term) ."%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
}**


if (!$result) {
echo "Could not successfully run query ($sql) from DB: " . mysql_error();
exit;
}

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
exit;
}


while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
echo '<br><br><div class="data1">';
echo htmlentities($row["FName"]);
echo '</div><br><div class="data2">';
echo htmlentities($row["LName"]);
echo '</div><br><div class="data3">';
echo htmlentities($row["Phone"]);
echo '</div>';
}

mysql_free_result($result);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Preventing the form from being submitted via JS is a quick fix, but you still need to handle the possibility that someone could STILL submit a blank search:

```
if (isset($_POST['term']) && ($_POST['term'] !== '')) {
   $term = $_POST['term'];
   $safe_term = mysql_real_escape_string($term);
   $sql = "...."
   blah blah blah
}
```

note the use of mysql_real_escape_string(). It is **THE** safe method for strings in mysql queries. addslashes is a hideously broken piece of crap and should NEVER be used for SQL injection prevention.

Comment: Ah thanks for the advice, is this meant to go instead of what I have or added? If so where a bouts is it going? Thanks!

Comment: Just a simple skeleton to partially replace+enhance what you've got. The important part is wrapping your whole query logic in the if() so the query is only performed IF something was actually submitted. You can add an 'else' case to do something like `echo "No search terms provided"`.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I've got it! I have updated my question php code, is this what you mean? I have put ** around the part I edited. Also what can I put instead of the $term = addcslashes($term,'%_');

Comment: The entire fetch results/display results part could be in the if() block as well. Your code as is will fail as you're trying to fetch results from a query that may never have run.

Comment: What would the if wrapper look like for that? I am trying to relate it to the if wrapper above or is it completely different?

Comment: `if (has search term) { do data base search + fetch + display } else { complain about lack of search terms }`

Comment: Thanks for youth help so far! What shall i put instead of the $term = addcslashes($term,'%_'); line of code. I am so stuck on that. I changed it to $term = mysql_real_escape_string($term,'%_'); but it was an error

Comment: http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string   the second argument must be a DB link handle.

Comment: Thank you but I'm still quite confused on how to improve it. Is there another link that can put me in the exact direction I'm looking for? Are there any other parts i need to make safer to prevent injection?

Comment: Thanks! Ill check it out, how do people know when their mysql/php script is completely free from mysql injection? I feel like it will never be protected!

Comment: They use PDO or mysqli with prepared statements, which cover most cases. But prepared statements can't handle all query constructs so sometimes you have to go bare metal anyways.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the length in JS and abort is it's blank

Comment: Thanks, do you know any sites that can help or what i should type in google because I am finding it difficult to get a definite answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that using javascript.
Add a javascript function to handle on click event of submit button.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm(event)" />
```

Inside that javascript function, check whether textbox is empty or not

```
        function submitForm(event){
        var val = document.getElementsByName('term')[0].value;

        if (val==null || val.trim()==""){
        //document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit();
         event.preventDefault();
         return false;

        }
        else {
          return true;
        }

        }
```

If empty, prevent default event and return false => prevent submission
if not empty, return true => submit the form.

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. the input i am testing is this: http://www.weezy.co.uk/form.html why is it not working for me?

Comment: I updated the answer for passing event object to submitForm function and use event object to prevent default behaviour if text box value is empty.

Comment: Thanks! works great. Do you know how to stop all results returning when entering '%' in the input?